# In HTML5 canvas, is it possible to rotate an object around a rotating object?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am faced with the challenge of rotating an object (a) with the center point at the center of the canvas, and have object (b) rotate around a dynamic axis relative to the rotation of object (a). The best example I can think of is the Solar system.

The relationship between

the sun - rotation axis of object (a),

the earth - relative point of object (a) to act as the rotation axis of object (b)

the moon - object (b)

I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Is it beyond canvas' capabilities?

Comment: If you consider that games are built in canvas... Yes, the Moon can rotate Earth. Earth can rotate Sun. It's just how you write your JS that makes the difference.

Comment: please show your code, it will be useful to recognize your questions more easily

Answer (score 0):

You should translate first, setting the origin to the center of the thing you want to orbit, and then rotate and the draw the orbiting thing relative to that new origin.